# How to find best-fit line between two columns in Pandas Dataframe, but split up by each individual group (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that, when simplified, looks something like:

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 3.3 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 |
| 7 | 0 | 0.2 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 6 |
| 7 | 5 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 | 9 |

However, there are more columns (19 total) with other info, and there are thousands of rows, with **70+ unique 'ID' numbers**.

What I want is to, for each ID 'group', calculate the best-fit line between X and Y, and store that information as something like:

| ID | Slope | Intercept | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.95 | 0.70 | 0.99 |
| 7 | 1.34 | 0.08 | 0.88 |

which summarizes this best-fit information for each 'ID'. Here Slope and Intercept are the slope and intercept of the linear best-fit line, and R2 is the R-squared value for some measure of error.

I can of course do this manually using something like:

```
import scipy
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(a, b)
r2 = r_value**2
```

which is how I filled those in in the second table. But how could I automate this for all the rows within in each 'ID' group? I imagine using df.groupby('ID') somehow, but I don't know how to combine both methods at a large scale...

Any help welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `ID` and then use `apply`:

```
res = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: scipy.stats.linregress(x['X'], x['Y']))
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(res.tolist(), index=res.index).reset_index().round(2)
```

Output:

```
>>> stats_df
   ID  slope  intercept  rvalue  pvalue  stderr
0   2   1.95       0.70    0.99    0.01    0.17
1   7   1.34       0.08    0.94    0.02    0.28
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly for some/most of my columns, for others I seem to get 'nan' for slope, intercept etc., but I think that's a data issue which I will try and fix myself (probably my nan values?) Thanks!

Comment: @ richardec If I wanted to instead add these as columns in the original dataframe, is there an easy way to do that?
I just want to be able to plot the original X,Y lines for each ID group (all in same plot), but color code the entire line according the the slope or r2 value for that ID...

Comment: By this code, you're reducing the number of rows, so are you thinking to just copy the values to all rows of the df? E.g., `slope` for `ID = 2` in the stats df is `1.95`, so are you thinking to copy `1.95` for each row in the original df where `ID = 2`?

Comment: @g.is.stuck never mind all that; try this: `df = pd.concat([df, stats_df.set_index('ID').loc[df['ID']].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Comment: thank you so much! Yes that's exactly right, I just wanted those repeating rows with those numbers as exra columns. I tried your code and it worked super well in that it added the three extra columns - BUT, everywhere else is now a 'nan', and the df is almost twice as long (in rows). Sometimes the nans are in the main columns, sometimes they are in the new three columns, sometimes in all columns. It makes no sense! But I'll work on it, I'm sure I'm missing something. Thank you!